# Move subview after rotated superview iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, rotation, subview

I have a `subview`, it is `UIImageView` and I have a `superview` - uiview.

I add subview to superview. At begin, I move subview using code:

```
float difx = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:subview].x - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:subview].x;

float dify = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:subview].y - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:subview].y;

subview.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(subview.transform, difx, dify);
```

and it move very good!(it move towards a finger-cursor) .

But if i rotate superview, using code:

`superview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(angle));`

at this time, subview does not move correct, not right! (it does not move towards a finger-cursor)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransform t, CGFloat angle)
```